# LWC: Building JS dependencies from NPM modules

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, libraries

To take advantage of NPM's audit, update, and other capabilities, I'm a firm believer that developers should use a package manager like NPM to manage JavaScript libraries that they import in their Lightning Components.

The question "can we use NPM packages in LWC" [has already been asked](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304642) -- and yes, we can. But how to get those packages bundled in a repeatable way so they can be imported by a component is not well documented. Browserify has been mentioned in some contexts, but I'm not aware of any published Browserify + LWC how-to's anywhere.

A helpful build process might create static resources to be imported, LWC utility bundles, or JS files within existing LWC bundles that contain import statements. I'm open to any of these approaches. I just think the LWC developer community is due for some better package management practices, and a good answer to this question could go a long way in making our Lightning Components more powerful, secure, and maintainable.